# Always visible drawing on form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I want to draw always visible cross over picturebox on winform. I know ho to use Graphics and it's method DrawLine. But problem is that, painted cross is hidden behind the picturebox. this textbox is continually refreshed and this cross should be always visible.
Do you have some solution for this?

Here is code:

```
Point picBoxLocation = pictureBox.Location;
Size picBoxSize =  pictureBox.Size;

Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 5);

Point left = new Point(picBoxLocation.X, picBoxSize.Height/2);
Point right = new Point(picBoxLocation.X+picBoxSize.Width, picBoxSize.Height / 2);
Point up = new Point((picBoxLocation.X + picBoxSize.Width) / 2, picBoxLocation.Y);
Point bottom = new Point((picBoxLocation.X + picBoxSize.Width) / 2, (picBoxLocation.Y+picBoxSize.Height)/2);

Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
graphics.DrawLine(myPen, left,  right);
graphics.DrawLine(myPen, up, bottom);
```

Comment: CreateGraphics() is like a virus in .NET programs.  Always use the Paint event to draw.

Comment: Which method/which event is this code in?

Comment: I tried Form_Paint, and also pictureBox_paint.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Whatever you draw with the Graphics object you get from CreateGraphics() are just pixels you splatter onto the screen.  How long they survive is crapshoot, not very long at all on XP, longer when you use Aero.  Simple things like moving the window off the screen or minimizing + restoring the window will make them disappear.  Without Aero it just takes moving another window across yours.  CreateGraphics() is only appropriate if you don't care about that.  Which is rare, a program has to update the screen at a high rate so it quickly redraws what was lost.  Like a game with a high frame rate.

Comment: @Hans Passant OK, but how to draw on form to have it always visible and over control?

Comment: Use the Paint() event **of the PICTUREBOX** if you want to draw on that control.  In that event, there is a graphics supplied via `e.Graphics` that you use.  Make sure you change your drawing code so that it uses **client** coords with respect to that PictureBox.  The point (0, 0) will be in the upper left of that control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get Graphics object in OnPaint callback:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(...);
}
```